# Showing hiding multiple href elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I'm attempting to hide multiple href element using pure javascript :

```
document.getElementById('test').onmouseover = function() {  document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown').setAttribute(
    "style", "display:block;");
                                                        } 
document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown').onmouseout = function() { document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown').setAttribute(
    "style", "display:none;");
                                                        } 

.hideDropDown {
   z-index:9999; 
    display:none; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color:red
}

.displayDropDown {
   z-index:9999; 
    display:block; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color:red
}

document.getElementById('test').onmouseover = function() {  document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown').setAttribute(
    "style", "display:block;");
                                                        } 
document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown').onmouseout = function() { document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown').setAttribute(
    "style", "display:none;");
                                                        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w55yubtc/24/

But error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).setAttribute is not a function` is being thrown. How to set the styles of multiple elements using pure javascript? In this case hide/display href elements ?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown')` will return an array, you'll have to loop through

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName('...')[index].style.display = "none"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName(...)` delivers a `NodeList`, an [array-like](http://www.2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-array-like-objects.html) object. If you want to use `.setAttribute`, you have to loop through it:

```
for (var i=0; i < myNodelist.length; i+=1) {
  myNodelist[i].setAttribute( ... );
}
```

anyway, you can solve this using *no scripting at all*:

```css
.dropDown {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    display: none;
}

li[data-hover]:hover > .dropDown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li data-hover="true">
  <a id="test" href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
  <br>    
  <a class="dropDown" href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
  <a class="dropDown" href="www.google.com">Hello2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Fixed a few typos in there

Comment: @RGraham Thnx, you where faster than I was ;)

Comment: @blue-sky: there's only one `<li>` element in your html. The hrefs (`.dropDown`) are positioned `absolute` in the css, that's why they're overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use querySelectorAll and CSS classes rather than the style attribute.  The advantage of querySelectorAll is you have more control than just the class, using CSS classes avoids collisions with direct access to the style attribute.

```
var hideList = document.querySelectorAll("a.test, a.dropDown");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < hideList.length; i++) {
    if (hideList[i].className.indexOf("hidden") === -1) {
        hideList[i].className += " hidden";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('test').onmouseover = function () {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
    }
}

document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown')[1].onmouseout = function () {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('dropDown');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ekmp7d5/)

**P.S.** *This solution is for this question only, there are better solutions to this approach (like css only)*